# Less visibility in child property c#

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a base class with a public property.

```
public class Parent 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I want that field will be calculated in the child constructor

```
public class Child1 : Parent 
{
     public Child1(string a, string b)
     {
         this.Name = a + " " + b;
     }
}
```

And I want to mask or decrease visibility of `Name` in the child.

That we **will not** be able to do

```
var l = new Child1("aa", "bb");
l.Name = "something else";
```

I am pretty sure that what I am trying to achieve is impossible and against *Liskov substitution principle*.

Any idea about this?

Comment: Would changing the accessors to `{ get; protected set; }` do the trick for you? Or do you have other constraints? ie. is the `Child1` class allowed to set the property after the constructor?

Comment: You may use the ‘new’ modifier in the child class to hide the parent property

Comment: You can do what @Béranger said, but note that it creates 2 separates properties. You will not be able to access a `Child`'s `Name` through a variable of type `Parent`.

Comment: "and against Liskov substitution principle." Yeap, that´s it. The point of an **Is A**-relation is that a child behaves the same way as its parent and can seemlessly be replaced by any other type implementing the same base-type. So the only way to achieve this is by changing the base-type.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @sr28 I have an old attribute that I want to expand, but I can't change old code.

Comment: @Béranger can you elaborate how the `new` modifier will help me here

Answer (score 1):

Why not passing name to Parent constructor like that?

```
public class Parent 
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }  // private set; can be skipped

    public class Parent(string name)     
    {          
        Name = name;       
    }
}
```

Then Child class would look like this

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(string a, string b)
       : base(a + b)
    { }
}
```

If you are not able to make change in base class there is alternative solution (partially only)

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public new string Name 
    { 
        get => base.Name;
        private set => base.Name = value;       
    }

    public Child(string a, string b)
    {
        Name = $"{a} {b}";
    }
}
```

But there is quick workaround for encapsulation...

```
Child c = new Child("abc", "def");
c.Name = "New name"; // this will cause compilation error

Parent p = c;        // this is perfectly legal
p.Name = "HACKED!";
```

Comment: true, I focused on concept ;-)

Comment: If I could change parent class, I wouldn't had any problem. The problem is parent class is something I can't touch.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds less like a parent/child relationship or another case of Polymorphy.
I do not know of a accesor that would say "public in this class, but not inheritors". And not just for C#, but any OOP langauge I learned.

It sounds more like a a case for [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)):

```
public class Child1 {
    Parent _backingField; //Set in constructor

    public string ParentName {
       get { return _backingField.Name; }
       //No setter
    }
}
```

One of the first things you learn in MVVM: If polymorphy can not do that or you do not have enough control over the class, just encapsulate it into something you do have full control over.

Edit:
In a more advanced view, with a abstract base class:

```
public abstract class Person {
   public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Parent : Person {
    //I know of no property parent could have, that person does not
    //Even the concept of a parent name, sounds more like a "Person" thing
}

public class Child1 : Person {
    Parent _backingField; //Set in constructor

    public string ParentName {
       get { return _backingField.Name; }
       //No setter
    }
}
```

Alternatively, just make one class:

```
public class Person {
    //Every person has a parent
    Person _backingField; //Set in constructor

    public string ParentName {
       get { return _backingField.Name; }
       //No setter
    }
   //And of course it's own name
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I am not sure it's encaspsulation, I am sure that `Child1` is a `Parent`, and not `Child1` has a `Parent`

Comment: @Ygalbel If parent and child have things *other* then the Name property in common, that sounds like a common base class (like Person?) | Your naming problem is a XY Problem. You thought inheritance is the solution, so you named them like that (Y). But realy encapsualtion seems to be the solution. I just could not find a better name for those classes

Comment: You right, I have 10 more properties that are in common.

Comment: @Ygalbel Another look and it appears you should just have one class "PersoN" as the concept of having a Parent is pretty much universal among persons.

Comment: @Ygablbel : you want a class that _controls_ (put restrictions on) Parent. You don't want to _extend_ Parent with new functionality, another language hint that could lead you to the same conclusion that inheritance is not the right tool here,